# PhD with a supervisor who has not published anymore since 2014

Tags: phd, advisor

I'm finishing my master's degree in physics and I'm searching for a PhD position. A potential professor for PhD is almost 60 years old and he has not published any paper since 2014!

What do you think about this?

Comment: How regularly has he published up until 2014?

Comment: I think about 3 papers per year.

Comment: It's likely that he stopped caring about publishing himself and lets his students get all the glory.

Comment: So, is it advisable? I'm afraid, he has no motivations and projects anymore in head.

Comment: You could send him an e-mail and ask if he's taking on new students or projects at this point? also possible that he just has not bothered updating the place you looked for his publications.

Comment: Just ask about his current research interests.  In principle this should not be a show-stopper.

Answer (score 8):

You are concerned that this professor does not publish because she/he ran out of ideas and motivation. Although this could be the case, there are other possibilities, which I want to point to you:

- They are working on a very large and important textbook and don't have time to publish.
- They have a lot of PhD students and allow them to publish as a single author (a bit unusual these days, but still happens)
- They don't cope well with modern technology (computers, word processors, simulation tools, etc), and rely on their students to help them put their ideas into  final publication.

I suggest talking to professor and asking these questions face-to-face.

Comment: Option 1 seems realistic indeed and is impossible to find out without asking. Option 2 is realistic, too, but can be found without asking, assuming a website where the students are listed. Option 3 would be surprising, given that publication technology hasn't changed so much since 2014.

Comment: The Prof might've had a student until 2014, but no-one to assist later.